# Cannot find a Calculation of Flexible Statistics main code body

Tags: c, linux

I have a code where It wants to read which operation it wants to do and then calculate the numbers using the operation. I have the library code and header but the main code, I don't know what to implement within the body. I have a skeleton code however I'm drawing a blank on what else I need to do.

If this helps, the operation I'm trying to achieve is:

```
./statistics mean 10 20 30
```

and the answer should be: `20.0`

Library Header:

```
#ifndef MY_LIBRARY_H
#define MY_LIBRARY_H

float OP_MEAN(int size, float * values);
float OP_MAX(int size, float * values);
float OP_SD(int size, float * values);

#endif
```

Library Code:

```
float OP_MEAN(int size, float * values)
{
  int i;
  float sum = 0.0;
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    sum += values[i];
  }
  return sum/n;
}

float OP_MAX(int size, float * values)
{
  int i;
  float maximum = 0.0;
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if (values[i] > maximum)
    {
      maximum = values[i];
    }
  }
  return maximum;
}

float OP_SD(int size, float * values)
{
  float mean = OP_MEAN(size, values);
  float sum = 0.0, un_sqrt_sd = 0.0;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    sum += pow(double(values[i] - mean), double(2));
  }
  un_sqrt_sd = (float) sum / (size - 1);
  return (float) sqrt(double(un_sqrt_sd));
}
```

Main Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_lib.h"


// define the operations as enum here
enum operations{
  OP_MEAN
  OP_MAX
  OP_SD
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

//parse command line arguments

  enum operations op;
  // 1. find the operator
  if (strcmp(argv[1], "max") ...){ // check with man strcmp
    op = OP_MAX;
  }...
  // 2. define an array with the necessary size
  // 3. load numbers using my_atoi()
  float (*fp)(int size, float * values); // declared function pointer variable

  // use a switch to set the function pointer
  switch(op_var){
    case(OP_MAX):
      fp = ... // set the function pointer
  }

  // invoke the function pointer
  float result = fp(size, array)
  printf("%.1f\n", result);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest `float maximum = -FLT_MAX;` to handle an all negative input set.

Comment: `pow(double(values[i] - mean), double(2));` does not look like C code.  Sure you are using a C compiler?

Comment: In C, you can't have simultaneously a function `OP_MEAN` and an enumeration constant `OP_MEAN` — not in the same scope, anyway, yet you appear to be trying to do that with declarations at global scope.  So, you need to rethink your naming conventions.  Note that in C, all upper case names are usually reserved for macros and enumeration constants; the functions would normally be named in lower case or mixed case and not upper case.

Comment: Of course, if you're using a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler, you can get away with it — but the tag on the question is C.

Comment: OT: regarding: `float sum = 0.0;`  The literal is a `double` that is being stuffed into a `float`  To write a `float` literal, append a trailing `f` to the literal, I.E. `float sum = 0.0f;`